# MultiIndexing rows vs. columns in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, multi-index

I am working with multiindexing dataframe in pandas and am wondering whether I should multiindex the rows or the columns.

My data looks something like this:
[image: DataTable]

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
arrays = pd.tools.util.cartesian_product([['condition1', 'condition2'], 
                                          ['patient1', 'patient2'],
                                          ['measure1', 'measure2', 'measure3']])
colidxs = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, 
                                    names=['condition', 'patient', 'measure'])
rowidxs = pd.Index([0,1,2,3], name='time')
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(rowidxs), len(colidxs)), 
                    index=rowidxs, columns=colidxs)
```

Here I choose to multiindex the column, with the rationale that pandas dataframe consists of series, and my data ultimately is a bunch of time series (hence row-indexed by time here).

I have this question because it seems there is some asymmetry between rows and columns for multiindexing. For example, in [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#multiindex-query-syntax) document webpage it shows how `query` works for row-multiindexed dataframe, but if the dataframe is column-multiindexed then the command in the document has to be replaced by something like `df.T.query('color == "red"').T`.

My question might seem a bit silly, but I'd like to see if there is any difference in convenience between multiindexing rows vs. columns for dataframes (such as the `query` case above).

Thanks.

Comment: It really depends on how you want to manipulate, output and.or view your data. I suspect multi indexing on the rows is more useful (and possibly more efficient although I really don't know). If you're planning on manipulating ranges of data indexed by column then yeah, multi-columns are better for you.

Comment: This is a good question as there are certain fields where the data sets are usually time series, but may fall into a series of categories as shown in the example.  Insight on MultiIndex by column would be helpful.

Comment: Did you come up with any conclusion? I assume yes after 7+ years :-) It'd be helpful to share what orientations you end up choosing and why (i.e. depending on your queries and etc...).

Answer (score 1):

A rough personal summary of what I call the row/column-propensity of some common operations for DataFrame:

- `[]`: column-first
- `get`: column-only
- attribute accessing as indexing: column-only
- `query`: row-only
- `loc, iloc, ix`: row-first
- `xs`: row-first
- `sortlevel`: row-first
- `groupby`: row-first

"row-first" means the operation expects row index as the first argument, and to operate on column index one needs to use `[:, ]` or specify `axis=1`;
"row-only" means the operation only works for row index and one has to do something like transposing the dataframe to operate on the column index.

Based on this, it seems multiindexing rows is slightly more convenient.

A natural question of mine: why don't pandas developers unify the row/column propensity of DataFrame operations? For example, that `[]` and `loc/iloc/ix` are two most common ways of indexing dataframes but one slices columns and the others slice rows seems a bit odd.

Comment: loc/iloc/ix are multi axis indexers able to index all axes at the same time; [] only handles columns and is a dict like accessor; these are pretty distinct and useful in their own right. the most common ops are probably [] accessing; making it harder to do this would just make code more verbose

Comment: Did you come up with any conclusion? I assume yes after 7+ years :-) It'd be helpful to share what orientations you end up choosing and why (i.e. depending on your queries and etc...). or @Jeff may elaborate.